# Simple loading before a success message

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement something really simple, where I want to display a loading between messages. [A live example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k5n3l0pn9v)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      submitSuccess: false
    };
  }

  onClick = () => {
    console.log("click");
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      submitSuccess: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>click</button>
        {this.state.isLoading ? (
          <p>loading...</p>
        ) : this.state.submitSuccess ? (
          <p>sucess!</p>
        ) : (
          <p>are you sure?</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is this example below:

1. Are you sure?
2. Loading...
3. Success!

But I'm not doing this right, since I'm not working properly with the ternary operators. How can I improve this?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed here: https://codesandbox.io/s/rln4oz4vwq

Basic idea: Set loading to false by default, because you are not loading anything. On click of button, set loading to true as you truly are. Then on completion of async stuff, set loading to false and submitSuccess to true to indicate you are done.

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      submitSuccess: false
    };
  }

  onClick = () => {
    console.log("click");
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true
    });

    //lets assume you now do some async stuff and after 2 seconds you are done
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        submitSuccess: true
      });
    }, 2000);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>click</button>
        {this.state.isLoading ? (
          <p>loading...</p>
        ) : this.state.submitSuccess ? (
          <p>success!</p>
        ) : (
          <p>are you sure?</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! :)